# Angular-Meteor Pagination

Tags: angular-meteor

I would like to use a Pagination for my Angular-Meteor app. Unfortunately, I have not found an official package for this. But I found this package: https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages.
I use the md-data-table for my app: https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table
I have only no idea how I can use the two packages together. My table looks like this:

```
<table md-table>
 <tr md-row>
   <th><span>My Prop</span></th>
 </tr>
 </td>
    <td md-cell>{{myprop.value}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Can I use the meteor-pages package to return a cursor I can use, or how could I connect this two different packets?

Answer (score 0):

The official angular meteor site suggests that you use angular-utils-pagination package:

```
meteor npm install --save angular-utils-pagination
```